# Facebook Graph API HTTP POST Photo Upload

Tags: c#, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing some playing with HTTP Posts, and wondered if someone could help me out with the ways to upload a photo to facebook using HTTP Post request. I have an access token, and can access the user's data, including ID, name, etc. But figuring out the uri for the upload is a big confusing.

I'm implementing the code in C#, and most (if not all) online resources are for php.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read this:

[graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

You have 2 different ways in your task.

- Uploading photo to album
- Posting photo as part of link posting

If you want to upload photo, you need to configure request like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ALBUM_ID_IN_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_UPLOAD_PHOTO}
/photos?
message={MESSAGE_THAT_YOU_WANT_ADD_TO_PHOTO}&
source={SOURCE_OF_PHOTO}&
place={PLACE_NOT_INTERESTING}&
access_token={YOU_KNOW_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Also, you may have a look at [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)

Comment: I assume by this I'll need to use a third party to temporarily host the photo? Or will a local source be good enough?

Comment: it's better to look third party